# How to Get HtmlHelper in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When using the MVC 6.0 beta1, I can see in the MVC source that there is a utility [DefaultTemplatesUtilities.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/5e067cdb9ecf7d910d45a427aef4e293c3d68801/test/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.Test/Rendering/DefaultTemplatesUtilities.cs) to GetHtmlHelper. But this HtmlHelper only returns formatted output that is setup in CreateViewEngine() method.

How can I create a `viewEngine` so that the normal html is rendered.

I need to get `HtmlHelper` through code and use it to generate some html. i.e. `htmlHelper.EditorFor(model=>model.Property)`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Every view page (CSHTML) file in an MVC 6 app has access to the HTML helper by just typing `@Html.TextBox(...)` etc.

Comment: I need to generate Editors for the object's properties through the code. I can simply use Html.EditorFor in the views, but need to do it in the controller. My objective is to have something that will auto generate editors based on complex models i.e. classes with Lists of Custom Objects as properties.  

Using DefaultTemplatesUtilities.cs in mvc source, i am able to get HtmlHelper based on supplied Model. But I am unable to get Editors.

Comment: I am going to close this one and ask a new question with better wording

Comment: If it's your own question I think you can see a `delete` button under the question (near the tags) to just delete it instead of trying to close it.

Comment: I think what he wants is to create a ViewModel with a `IHtmlString` property created inside the index method of a controller.
I don't think you can create HTML markup from inside the controller because this is pre view engine rendering stage - HtmlHelpers are for views to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get HtmlHelper using Dependency Injection to your controller constructor.

Check my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902545/how-does-mvc-6-renders-a-view/34955964#34955964) for more detailed code.