# Create HtmlHelper in Controller to generate editors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to create editors for model properties through ajax calls. Similar to this  http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2014/08/how-to-dynamically-via-ajax-add-new-items-to-a-bound-list-model-in-asp-mvc-net/

Please see the htmlHelperExtension in the above article. How can I create a similar extension in mvc 6 ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to start to look to asp.net tag helpers.

https://github.com/DamianEdwards/TagHelperStarterWeb
this is the version of the starter web site developer using tag helpers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the answer in [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620322/create-get-defaulthtmlgenerator-from-mvc-controller/34621813#34621813)

What you need to do is use DefaultHtmlGenrator injected to the controller to generate your editors.

Answer (score 0):

You can get HtmlHelper using Dependency Injection to your controller constructor.

Check my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902545/how-does-mvc-6-renders-a-view/34955964#34955964) for more detailed code.