# @Html.Raw equivalent in MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have several controls that are copy-pasted. I want to avoid it, so I moved all HTML generating logic in static helper class. But when I use it my HTML is escaped in quotes, but I want to display it in raw HTML. Here is two problems:

1. I cannot extend controller itself, I should do it from a view only.
2. I cannot use tag helpers, becuase one of parameters is of delegate type, so it cannot be passed to tag helper class (as far as I know).

My current usecase was:

```
<div class="panel-body panel-body-table">
    @(WuiHelper<int>.RenderIntegerInput(Model.Config, x => x.PatchSize, "sourceObserver_patchSize", "Patch Size", 1, 1000000))
</div>
```

But as I said, it escapes an html in quotes so it renders as plain text (return type of method is `string`).
It seems that `@Html` helper class was removed. My current `web.config` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is a screenshot: all namespaces are referenced, but `@Html` is missing:
[image]

Comment: @Html.Raw exists in aspnetcore, you can still use it

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27895578/728795

Comment: @JoeAudette well, I don't really see it. Maybe it was removed in RC2. I also tried `@Raw` and `@(new RawString())`, but they both are missing too.

Comment: @Andrei your post links a post where controller is modified, while I cannot do it.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy it was not removed in rc2 I'm using rc2 and just tested to make sure it is still there

Comment: @JoeAudette hmm, maybe I am missing some references in `web.config`? Unfortunly, ASP.Net core is not documented well yet, hard to google what should I reference to make it work. Some people says `use Html.Raw`, some peoples use home-written controllers, someone prefer `new RawString()`, someone just write `@Raw` and it works...

Comment: references/aka dependencies go in project.json not web.config

Comment: @JoeAudette AspNetCore.Mvc is referenced in `project.json`, this is why i decided that it's not enough.

Comment: this works in a view for me @Html.Raw("<b>this is bold</b>")

Comment: @JoeAudette see screenshot. I have all needed namespaces, but I haven't such method.

Comment: try @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering

Comment: it is strange, looks like you have the right dependencies, you can see the source here https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/HtmlHelper.cs only thing different in my app is you are targeting net452 and I'm targeting netstandard1.3

Comment: @JoeAudette well, it don't know what is happening just like you, but I found some workaround. It's just an RC2, so: "it happens".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `IHtmlContent` instead of `string` as return value of a method, and wrapping a string in `HtmlEncodedString`.
Entire signature worked:

```
public static IHtmlContent RenderIntegerInput<T>(CustomizableConfig<T> model, Func<T, TParam> func, string id, string name, int minValue, int maxValue)
{
   //...
   string oldStringResult = ... // generating HTML
   return new HtmlEncodedString(oldStringResult);
}
```